# Only first word is fetched and displayed from a sentence

Tags: php

I have two pages index.php and currentmovies.php. I am trying to display movie name for a given movie in currentmovies.php, but I am unable to display the entire name,  only the first word is being displayed. I have written my query in index.php and I am passing the values to currentmovies.php.

Eg: if the movie name is "Lord Of the Rings" only "Lord" is being displayed

//Code in index.php
    echo "";

```
//code in currentmovies.php
<?php 
echo "<b><font size='3'>Current Movie:",$_GET['movie_name']," </font></b>";

echo "<p> The movie ",$_GET['movie_name']," was released on ",$_GET['rdate']," and falls under the ",$_GET['genre']," category. </p>";
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you give us a get url dump? It's kinda hard to see what you are scraping if we don't have the source. Also is this coming off a form or selection?

Comment: why are you using commas after the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

```
//code in currentmovies.php
<?php 
echo "<b><font size='3'>Current Movie: ".$_GET['movie_name']."</font></b>";

echo "<p>The movie ".$_GET['movie_name']." was released on ".$_GET['rdate']." and falls under the ".$_GET['genre']." category.</p>";
```

Try this:

Answer (score -1):

Pleae do it this way:

```
<?php 
   echo '<b><font size="3">Current Movie: '.$_GET['movie_name'].' </font></b>';
   echo '<p> The movie '.$_GET['movie_name'].' was released on '.$_GET['rdate'].' and falls under the '.$_GET['genre'].' category. </p>';
```

Please remember, in this case dot instead of comma.

And one more thing:
If you don't use any variables inside quota, please use single quota, plus for html is much better and easier use single quota, in example:

```
 <font size="3">
```

Comment: @dareKevil your code is stating that the string for the $_GET function is to be printed in the echo, if OP were to use this, it would need to be quotes in the $_GET brackets like this: $_GET["movie_name"]